# Rails command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the tutorial at

http://api.rubyonrails.org/

to install Rails. However, when I run the Rails command, Rails new myapp in bash it creates the project new. When I try the command Rails server it creates the project server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

This seems like rails 2.x behavior.  Can you please verify which rails version you are running with:

```
rails -v
```

Comment: I figured out the issue myself, I ran ruby script/server inside the directory and the problem solved itself, thanks for taking the time and effort to try to help!

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to rails 3.

I recommend you to try using this: http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/download.html
Once on the installer, it'll tell you which dependecies you need for your OS and which commands you should run.